# Upgraded from 2020-2022R2:Unable to cast object of type 'APDocumentResult' to type 'PX.Data.PXResult`1[PX.Objects.AP.APDocumentEnq+APDocumentResult]'

Tags: c#, acumatica

I upgraded acumatica from 2020 R2 to 2022 R2. The customization was working well in 2020 R2 but in 2022 R2 it has given me the below error. Tried to troubleshoot but was unable to.
Got the following error on the VENDORS DETAILS;

> Unable to cast object of type 'APDocumentResult' to type 'PX.Data.PXResult`1[PX.Objects.AP.APDocumentEnq+APDocumentResult]'

Code:

```
    public PXSelectOrderBy<APDocumentEnq.APDocumentResult, OrderBy<Asc<APDocumentEnq.APDocumentResult.docDate>>> Documents;
    protected virtual IEnumerable documents()
    {
        decimal decCurrRunningBal = 0;
        decimal decRunningBal = 0;
        Dictionary<string, decimal> curydict = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();

        BqlCommand query = Base.Documents.View.BqlSelect;
        PXView view = new PXView(Base, true, query, Base.Documents.View.BqlDelegate);

        int intStartRow = PXView.StartRow;
        int intTotalRows = 0;

        

        List<Object> list = view.Select(PXView.Currents, PXView.Parameters, PXView.Searches, PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings, PXView.Filters, ref intStartRow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref intTotalRows);
        PXView.StartRow = 0;

        foreach (PXResult<APDocumentEnq.APDocumentResult> item in list)
        {
            APDocumentEnq.APDocumentResult row = item.GetItem<APDocumentEnq.APDocumentResult>();
            APRegisterExt registerExt = this.Base.Documents.Cache.GetExtension<APRegisterExt>(row);
            
            //KES Running Balance  
            decRunningBal += row.OrigDocAmt ?? 0;
            //ed
            //Foreign Running Balance
            if (row.CuryID != "KSHS")
            {
                if (curydict.ContainsKey(row.CuryID))
                {
                    curydict[row.CuryID] += row.CuryOrigDocAmt ?? 0;
                    decCurrRunningBal = curydict[row.CuryID];
                }
                else
                {
                    curydict[row.CuryID] = row.CuryOrigDocAmt ?? 0;
                    decCurrRunningBal = curydict[row.CuryID];
                }

                //ed decCurrRunningBal += row.CuryOrigDocAmt ?? 0;

            }
                registerExt.UsrCurrencyRbal = decCurrRunningBal;
                registerExt.UsrVenderbal = decRunningBal;
        }
        return list;
            
        }
         //CODE FOR DISPLAYING DOCUMENT TAX
        protected void APDocumentResult_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
          APDocumentEnq.APDocumentResult row = (APDocumentEnq.APDocumentResult)e.Row;
          if(row == null) return;
          APRegisterExt extObj = cache.GetExtension<APRegisterExt>(row);
          APInvoice invoiceObj = PXSelect<APInvoice, Where<APInvoice.refNbr, Equal<Required<APInvoice.refNbr>>,
            And<APInvoice.docType, Equal<Required<APInvoice.docType>>>>>.Select(this.Base, row.RefNbr, row.DocType);

          if(invoiceObj != null)
            {
              extObj.UsrTaxAmt = invoiceObj.CuryTaxTotal;
              //cache.SetValue<APRegisterExt.usrTaxAmt>(e.Row,invoiceObj.CuryTaxTotal);
              if(invoiceObj.CuryTaxTotal> 0) extObj.UsrTwopercent = (invoiceObj.CuryTaxTotal * 0.125m);
              //var result = invoiceObj.CuryTaxTotal * 0.125m;
              //if(invoiceObj.CuryTaxTotal> 0) cache.SetValue<APRegisterExt.usrTwopercent> (e.Row,result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: foreach (PXResult<APDocumentEnq.APDocumentResult> item in list)
        {}
This line is using PXResult

Answer (score 0):

change

```
foreach (PXResult<APDocumentEnq.APDocumentResult> item in list)
```

to

```
foreach(APDocumentEnq.APDocumentResult item in list)
```

the objects being returned from

```
view.Select(PXView.Currents, PXView.Parameters, PXView.Searches, PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings, PXView.Filters, ref intStartRow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref intTotalRows);
```

has changed

Comment: changed the code as suggested but got the following error:

Comment: APDocumentEnq.APDocumentResult' does not contain a definition for 'GetItem' and no accessible extension method 'GetItem' accepting a first argument of type 'APDocumentEnq.APDocumentResult' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: foreach (APDocumentEnq.APDocumentResult item in list)
            {

                 APDocumentEnq.APDocumentResult row = item.GetItem<APDocumentEnq.APDocumentResult>();
                APRegisterExt registerExt = this.Base.Documents.Cache.GetExtension<APRegisterExt>(row);

Comment: no need to use item.GetItem, just reference item.DACField directly